# How can I use my domain name to map into my Amazon EC2's public IP?

Tags: ip-address, dns, amazon-ec2

How to put my registered domain name into DNS server?
Is there any DNS server available in this world?

Answer (score 1):

I use Route 53 from Amazon and create A records pointing to my IP. From Route 53 it'll give you the name servers to setup with your registrar so that DNS is handled by Route 53. Now when people go to your website it'll route to Amazon for DNS and ec2 for hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you will have to set up your own dns server (as part of an EC2 server ?) and have the IP address of that dns server put in as your domain's main DNS.
I obviously don't know how your setup looks like, but you should be able to set up [BIND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND) and then change the entries of your domain wherever it's registered to point to that.

Comment: so it is possible to set up BIND in my own EC2 server and also act as web server?

Comment: according to http://serverfault.com/questions/252298/link-a-domain-to-a-amazon-ec2-instance you can just add an A or CNAME entry at your registrar's website and it should be ok. There are quite a few questions concerning this on serverfault.